# Is there a way I can over ride a web site's CSS with my own?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hosting, overriding

Every day I use a web site which has a really great flash card system for language learning.

However, the authors of the site seem to have a really bizarre sense of what makes for good usability. They make font sizes so large that you only get a few lines of text per screen, and you have to scroll down to access buttons. And don't get me started on what it's like to access the site from a mobile device.

I've been in contact with the developers of the site, and I have even written CSS and header code for them in order to try and help. While they're nice people, unfortunately they have for months been unwilling or able to make changes.

So, I'm going rogue... I want to be able to impose my own damn CSS.

I vaguely remember this being a possibility in a Firefox addon, but can't seem to find it now.

In any case, because I aspire to use this on my mobile phone as well, here's the ideal solution:

I'd like to be able to set up a page on my web server that relays to the source web site, but over writes the CSS and displays it to me with my own CSS.

Is this possible? I know some CSS tricks to over write inline styles, but I'm much less clear on how I can set up a web page to relay the content of another page.

I hope my explanation and goals are clear. I will try to clarify more if I haven't conveyed any part of this properly.

Thank you for any tips.

Update: Here is the CSS I've placed in my userContent.css to try and get font size under control.

```
@-moz-document domain(badsite.com) {
body {
font-size: 12px;
}
font {
 font-family: inherit !important;
font-size: inherit !important;
color: inherit !important;
}
}
```

Comment: First, try reducing the zoom.  If you can make everything fit just by reducing the zoom to, say 70%, this may be the simplest solution.  Many modern browsers support zooming in and out.  The web site designers probably have huge high-pixel screens.

Comment: Second, many modern browsers allow you to attach a "user agent stylesheet" to re-style sites.  User agent sheets usualy take precedence over the site's style sheets.

Comment: Stephen, if it were only a matter of font sizes, then zooming might work. But we're talking about a lot of styling problems. Also, if I zoom out to make the text a reasonable size, things like buttons shrink down to become ridiculously unusable. Thanks for the suggestions, though.

Comment: You can zoom the whole page, not just the fonts.  I am not talking about the Text-Size setting.

Comment: FYI, the Firefox Add-on you're referring to is called [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) which is also [available for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) now too.

Comment: Stephen, yes, I know one can zoom the whole page. Look, the point is that when someone has a whole page of mismatched sizes, a global zoom is not helpful, as when you adjust one thing, other things become ridiculously small or large in relation.

Comment: Marcel, thanks for that tip. I will check out Stylish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can edit `userContent.css` in Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html). Use the [`@-moz-document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@-moz-document) to target that site only.

```
@-moz-document domain(bad-ui-site.com) {
   body {
      font-size: 80%;
   }
}
```

> I'd like to be able to set up a page on my web server that relays to the source web site, but over writes the CSS and displays it to me with my own CSS

I'd recommend you don't. It is difficult, and probably violates their terms.

Comment: Good tip. 
This might be one way to go, though like I mentioned, I think maybe a server side solution is the way to go.
Unless... if I can do something similar on my Android phone to over ride the CSS similar to what you've done there, then between the two solutions I may have what I need.

Comment: @ebisudave I'm not familiar with Android, so I can't help you there sorry.

Comment: Hmm... This isn't working. I've got userContent.css in my profile directory for Firefox, and I've added the following code to negate <font> tags and apply a 12px font size. Any idea where I'm going wroing?
`@-moz-document domain(badsite.com)`
`url(http://www.badsite.com/),`
`url-prefix(http://www.badsite.com/) {
`font[style] {`
`font-family: inherit !important;`
`font-size: inherit !important;`
`color: inherit !important;`
`}`
`body {`
`font-size: 12px;`
`}`
`}`

Comment: @ebisudave That is very difficult to read inline, can you please edit your original question and place this CSS?

Comment: Sorry, I suck at comments. I thought I used the minimarkdown. I added the code to the original uestions.

Comment: @ebisudave You should just be able to use `domain(bad-ui-site.com)`.

Comment: By the way, I've tried also using just @-moz-document domain(badsite.com), but that doesn't work, which is why I tried adding the others to see if that had an effect.

Comment: Got it! Two things - one is that the badsite had some crazy embedded font sizing on div tags which were obscurring the edits I was trying to make. Also: Firefox needs to be restarted after every userContent.css edit - refreshing the page is not enough. A bit of a miss on Firefox's part in my opinion, but there it is. I have control of the CSS now (more or less), so thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the FireFox Addon you are referring to is [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/)

As for the problem you're having, I thought that Internet Explorer let you define your own default styles for Web Pages?

Comment: @J.T.S.: No, pretty sure it's [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/).

Comment: Ah! Yep! Go with @Marcel, Stylish , not Firebug

Comment: Stylish or the Web Developer Toolbar (CSS > Add User Stylesheet)

Answer (score 0):

depending on the site structure and it's security, it may be possible to use your own site as a proxy for it. In this manner, you would have the power to change any client-side content such as css,js and html.
This is very unlikely to happen, because it would imply a great effort to "redirect" a whole site to another one; in many cases, if the site is not secured, it surely has a server-side functionality that you want to use in your proxy and which you can't "copy" with this method.